# Issue with making a build for iOS platform

Tags: ios, ionic4, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to make a build for iOS platform with

`ionic cordova build ios --device --prod --release --configuration=prod --verbose`

and am getting the following error:

> error: exportArchive: "AppName.app" requires a provisioning profile with
>   the Associated Domains and Push Notifications features.

Both my Ad hoc and development provisioning profiles have Associated Domains and Push Notifications are listed in Enabled capabilities, as well as in Xcode under Signing & Capabilities. To double check I re-generated provisioning profiles, downloaded them, but still no luck with making a build.

[image]

Could someone please suggest what I can do/check to resolve the issue with making the build.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are completely logged into your Apple Developer account through Xcode, that should clear up your issue.

If you are logged in and this continues, ensure that your 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' portal on https://developer.apple.com has associated notification certificates for the app, among that.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is missing the Provisioning profile which includes Push Notifications in it. 
Remove all the previously added profiles from your keychain and then make a fresh start by creating new Certificates and Provisioning Profiles.
Make sure to use the same Apple ID for creating certificates and to login in Xcode.

1. First try to create build only with development Profiles and
2. Then by adding the iOS distribution Profiles.